# Backbone.js serialization with json roots

Tags: json, persistence, backbone.js

I found that backbone.js expects json in the following form:

> {"id":5,"title":"Foo","body":"bar"}

However, I find having json roots reasonable, especially when the models get nested and related to other models. How can I convince backbone.js to understand json this way:

> {"message":{"id":5,"title":"Foo","body":"bar"}}

?

Comment: do you want to display it in the template?

Comment: I see that taking advantage of the templates fully could be a problem. Yes, I would like to use it in a template.

Answer (score 1):

This question could mean two things:

- you have a JSON and want to instantiate a new model
- or you have a web service that provides you with the following string

As the first is rather trivial, I suppose you mean the second case.

If your web service spits out a JSON like this, you can overwrite the `parse` method of BackboneJS' models and collections.

Basically you can take of [Backbone's implementation of parse for models](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L330-332) and modify it to your needs.

In your case this should do the trick:

```
parse : function(resp, xhr) {
  return resp.message;
},
```

The implementation for collections might look different, I did not try it.

Comment: Does this solution change the behavior how Backbone.js both parses server response and serializes the model? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this will help. You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/kahhor/haPFD/

```
(function($){

    window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{"message":{"id":5,"title":"Foo","body":"bar"}}
});

window.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

        render: function() {
            template= _.template($('#template').html());
            $(this.el).html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
            $('#container').html(this.el);
        }
});

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var MyModel1 = new MyModel ();

    var MyView1 = new MyView ({model: MyModel1});
    MyView1.render();
});

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="template">
    <%= message.id %><br>
    <%= message.title %><br>
    <%= message.body %><br>

</script>
```